shadcn card - semantic HTML
when using card.tsx from shadcn I see that's a div styled with tailwind (the card itself). Should I change it to section instead of div for semantic HTML? should I change also the footer (adding footer for example), header (adding header tag) for semantic HTML ?
const Card = forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>>(
  ({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
    <div
      ref={ref}
      className={cn(
        "rounded-xl border bg-card text-card-foreground shadow-md",
        className,
      )}
      {...props}
    />
  ),
);

const CardHeader = forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>>(
  ({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
    <div
      ref={ref}
      className={cn("flex flex-col space-y-1.5 p-6", className)}
      {...props}
    />
  ),
);

const CardTitle = forwardRef<
  HTMLParagraphElement,
  HTMLAttributes<HTMLHeadingElement>
>(({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
  <h3
    ref={ref}
    className={cn("font-semibold leading-none tracking-tight", className)}
    {...props}
  />
));

const CardDescription = forwardRef<
  HTMLParagraphElement,
  HTMLAttributes<HTMLParagraphElement>
>(({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
  <p
    ref={ref}
    className={cn("text-sm text-muted-foreground", className)}
    {...props}
  />
));

const CardContent = forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>>(
  ({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
    <div ref={ref} className={cn("p-6 pt-0", className)} {...props} />
  ),
);
CardContent.displayName = "CardContent";

const CardFooter = forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>>(
  ({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
    <div
      ref={ref}
      className={cn("flex items-center p-6 pt-0", className)}
      {...props}
    />
  ),
);
CardFooter.displayName = "CardFooter";


A section is a thematic grouping of content, typically with a heading. A group of cards is considered a section, but not a single card. A page for a card with more details is also considered a section.
    Specifies a header for a document or section.
    Defines a footer for a document or section.
Overall, I don't think there is much difference;
it's just a logical conclusion. Experts can correct me if I'm wrong.
